# SQL DATEADD Not returning quarter ends

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use the DATEADD function to add a quarter to a date. My environment is MS Mgmt Studio (v17.7) and SQL Server Express (14.0.1000). Based in the UK.

The code I am using is very simple as below, I am just confused by the return values:

```
SELECT DATEADD(q,1,'1997-09-30')
```

I would expect a return value of '1997-12-31 00:00:00.000' but instead I am getting '1997-12-30 00:00:00.000) ie. 30th of the month rather than 31st.

I have tried searching Stack Overflow but not found any similar issues. My approach so far has been to try changing the parameters and date type eg:

`SELECT DATEADD(q,2,'1997-09-30')`  - returns 1998-03-30 00:00:00.000 (I would expect 1998-03-31 00:00:00.000)

`SELECT DATEADD(qq,1,'1997-09-30')` / `SELECT DATEADD(quarter,1,'1997-09-30')` - same result

I have also tried to use a parameter

```
declare @date datetime (also tried datetime2, smalldate, date)
set @date = ('1997-09-30')
SELECT DATEADD(q,1,@date)
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on where I am going wrong? Am I missing something with the DATEADD function or is there some environment variable somewhere I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: Try SELECT eomonth(DATEADD(q,1,'1997-09-30')) and see if that works. The issue you have is it is adding a quarter to the date you have. If you use 1997-12-30) you will  not get the correct result. Your best bet would be to use a date table.

Answer (score 6):

A quarter is defined as 3 months. why would you expect 3 months after `1997-09-30` to *not* be `1997-12-30`? You wouldn't expected `DATEADD(q,1,'20000101')` to return `'2000-06-30'` or `'2000-03-31'` would you?

If you want the end of the month for 3 months after a specific date, you can use `EOMONTH`:

```
SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(QUARTER,1,'19970930'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, useful comments from all that helped me resolve my issue. Does seem obvious in retrospect, I was passing in financial quarter ends e.g. '30/09/1997' thinking I could use the 'q' to move to future or previous financial quarter ends. My mindset was that DATEADD(m,3,'19970930') was how I would move forward months and somehow the 'q' had different functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a newer version of SQL Server, Larnu's answer is a great one. If you have an older (<2012) one that does not the [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, you can do it like this:

```
declare @date date
set @date = ('1997-09-30')
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(q,1,DATEADD(DAY,1,@date)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know.